# php how to get timezone name from timezone_name_from_abbr for Asia/Colombo

Tags: php, timezone

I want to get the timezone name as Asia/Colombo (Sri Lanka timezone name) from the `timezone_name_from_abbr()` method in PHP.

`timezone_name_from_abbr('IST',19800);` always returns `Asia/Calcutta`. How do I get the timezone name `Asia/Colombo` ?

Also I read Sri Lanka has no time abbreviation. It uses IST(Indian Standard Time)

Comment: Fact: Time zone abbreviations can be ambiguous.  The I in IST could be India, but might be Israel or Ireland.  Others are ambiguous too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not IST but IHST `timezone_name_from_abbr('IHST',19800)` for Asia/Colombo
You can found it with this function: http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
timezone_abbreviations_list()
```

In order to get an associative array containing dst, offset and the timezone name as said [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php)